# Most apps won't open, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bug-reporting, desktop-apps

I'm working with an Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a partition of a server, and accessing it through X2GO and PuTTY. The installation is mostly fresh except for having installed Qt Creator. Almost no apps can be opened: when I click on apps, either from the bottom left menu or from /usr/share/applications, nothing happens--not even an error message.

My colleagues are running seemingly identical installations on the same server without this problem, by following a common set of installation instructions. We have been unable to reproduce the problem. What could be the matter?

Incomplete list of apps that won't open:

- About
- LXtermianl
- Termianl
- Terminal Emulator
- Sudoku
- System Monitor
- Vim (GUI)
- Calculator
- Calendar
- Character map
- Date and Time
- Default Applications
- Firefox
- Web Browser
- Fonts

Apps that open normally:

- Qt Creator
- Thunderbird
- About Myself
- Desktop Preferences
- Task Manager